# How do I upload a file with Puppeteer Sharp?

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I'm using [Puppeteer Sharp](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp) to test my web app. My web app has a button that triggers an `<input type="file">` to let the user select a CSV file to upload.

How do I use that to upload a file when testing via Puppeteer Sharp? Just clicking the button isn't enough, because I need to give the browse-for-file dialog a path to the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Page.WaitForFileChooserAsync` to interact with the file chooser. The important thing to remember is you need to have the file chooser ready *before* you click the `<input type="file">`.

For example:

```cs
var fileChooserDialogTask = page.WaitForFileChooserAsync(); // Do not await here

await Task.WhenAll(fileChooserDialogTask, page.ClickAsync("input[type='file']"));

var fileChooser = await fileChooserDialogTask;
await fileChooser.AcceptAsync(pathToFile);
```

If you try to click the `<input type="file">` before you've called `WaitForFileChooserAsync`, you'll be stuck with the modal file chooser dialog waiting for you to do something.